# VSCode: Is there a syntax to exclude all and only folders (not files at root of Workspace)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried this syntax:

```
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/**/": true
    }
```

But it doesn't work. It excludes files also.

Comment: Here you would need a pattern that includes everything except paths, that include a `.`. With a glob pattern you can only define what shall be included. Therefore I think it is not possible.